# Django REST Framework: Validate Serialiser List Update (PUT) with no pk and UNIQUE index on two fields

Tags: django, rest, api, validation

I have spent a few days on this and have read around the houses (i have rtfm several times... perhaps I have not understood tfm though). Come close to a few answers and I fear that in the end it is my knowledge of how Django / Serilizers (sic) work that is the problem.

I will start with my base problem to keep things simple, rather than any of the numerous attempts I have made to get this working.

I am attempting to do the following:

1. (**working**) GET a list of values from a Django rest_framework API
   based on a dual index, one field of which is passed in the URL
   (control_sys) and multiple values of a second field is passed in
   (JSON) data submitted to the API (transactionID).
2. (**not working**) Update (PUT) a list of values based on the same
   logic as the GET (above).
3. (**haven't got this far**) Create (POST) a list of values based on
   the same logic as the GET(above).

As indicated, the GET statement is working. The view is retrieving a queryset based on a list of transactionIDs and the control_sys (sysID) passed in the URL. It is passing this to the serialiser and returning the data via the API.

The update (PUT) is not working. My issue seems to be that I have not passed the pk (id field) of the model to the API and it is not available in the data posted to the API. I instead need to retrieve the query set in the same way as the GET statement and pass this for an update, at which point when I try to validate the seriliser I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

Which is being raised by the validator on line 155 of [Django Rest Framework Validator Code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/validators.py)

I am confused as I have checked and each item in the queryset has a value id, (which is returned when I reference pk) . I have also tried updating the data in the view to append a pk / id value to no avail.

I am passing the 'many=True' so that the seriliser knows that it is a queryset that it is receiving rather than a single model instance.

Thus far I have tried:

1. Appending id and pk to request.data
2. Various attempts at adding the id and pk explicitly to the seriliser using required=True/False and read_only=True/False
3. Subclassing the ListSerializer and using the META: list_serializer_class to control how the seriliser works.

I know it is the validation that is failing but I dont know how to fix this.

Any suggestions very welcome.

Some reference info below... I will post more on request.

**Model:**

```
 ## Comms Queue
class CommsQueue(models.Model):
    # primary key
    # foreign key
    control_sys = models.IntegerField("Control system foreign key (passive)", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    meter = models.IntegerField("Meter foreign key (passive)", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    # string
    data = models.CharField("Comm data", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    # int
    transactionID = models.BigIntegerField("Comms Transaction ID", blank=True, null=False)
    source = models.IntegerField("Originating source for event", blank=True, null=False)
    target = models.IntegerField("Target destination for event", blank=True, null=False, db_index=True)
    priority = models.IntegerField("Comms priority", blank=True, default=0)
    # url
    URI = models.URLField("Comm URI",max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    # bool
    #comm_send = models.BooleanField("Event requires uplink/downlink", blank=False, default=True) # TODO delete?
    comm_sent = models.BooleanField("Uplink/Downlink sent", blank=True, default=False)
    complete_req = models.BooleanField("Require completion notice", blank=True, default=False)
    complete = models.BooleanField("Event complete", blank=True, default=False)
    # date
    create_date = models.DateTimeField("Date created", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    last_date = models.DateTimeField("Date accessed", auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("control_sys","transactionID"),)
        index_together = [("control_sys","transactionID"),]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Transaction ID: %s, Complete: %s" % (str(self.transactionID), str(self.complete))
```

**Serilizer**:

```
class CommsSerialiser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
URI = ParameterisedHyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="comms-detail", lookup_fields=(('control_sys', 'sysID'), ('transactionID', 'tID')), read_only=True)
# convert MySQL bool to int bool
complete_req = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)
complete = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)

class Meta:
    model = CommsQueue
    fields = ('control_sys', 'meter', 'data', 'transactionID', 'source', 'target', 'priority', 'complete_req', 'complete', 'URI')

    validators = [
        UniqueTogetherValidator(
            queryset=CommsQueue.objects.all(),
            fields=('control_sys', 'transactionID')
        )
    ]
```

**View**:

```
class CommsDetail(APIView):
"""
Retrieve, update or delete MULTIPLE comms from queue.

"""
# session permissions
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsAuthedCommQueue,)

def get_object(self, sysID, transactionID_list):
    try:

        # get comms queue for control unit ...allow retrieve of complete comms
        comm_objects = CommsQueue.objects.filter(control_sys=sysID,transactionID__in=transactionID_list)

        # Auth user for control unit
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, comm_objects[0])

        # get object
        return comm_objects

    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        raise Http404


def get(self, request, sysID, format=None):

    # build list of transaction ID to retrieve
    transactionID_list = []
    for transaction in request.data:
        transactionID_list.append(transaction['transactionID'])

    comms = self.get_object(sysID,transactionID_list)
    serializer = CommsSerialiser(comms, context={'request': request}, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def put(self, request, sysID, format=None):

    # build list of transaction ID to retrieve
    transactionID_list = []
    for transaction in request.data:
        transactionID_list.append(transaction['transactionID'])
        print transaction

    comms = self.get_object(sysID,transactionID_list)
    serializer = CommsSerialiser(comms, data=request.data, context={'request': request}, many=True)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**'print serilizer' output:**

```
CommsSerialiser(<QuerySet[
    <CommsQueue: TransactionID: 313011,
    Complete: False>,
    <CommsQueue: TransactionID: 313013,
    Complete: False>,
    <CommsQueue: TransactionID: 313102,
    Complete: False>
]>,
context={
    u'request': <rest_framework.request.Requestobject>
},
data=[
    {
        u'control_sys': 710017,
        u'complete': 1,
        u'data': u'"{data innit}"',
        u'URI': u'http: //172.16.32.40: 8000/api/0.1/comm/710017/313102/',
        u'transactionID': 313102,
        u'complete_req': 1
    },
    {
        u'control_sys': 710017,
        u'complete': 1,
        u'data': u'"{data innit}"',
        u'URI': u'http: //172.16.32.40: 8000/api/0.1/comm/710017/313011/',
        u'transactionID': 313011,
        u'complete_req': 1
    },
    {
        u'control_sys': 710017,
        u'complete': 1,
        u'data': u'"{data arg}"',
        u'URI': u'http: //172.16.32.40: 8000/api/0.1/comm/710017/313013/',
        u'transactionID': 313013,
        u'complete_req': 1
    }
],
many=True): 
    control_sys = IntegerField(allow_null=True, label='Control system foreign key (passive)', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, required=False)
    meter = IntegerField(allow_null=True, label='Meter foreign key (passive)', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, required=False)
    data = CharField(allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, label='Comm data', max_length=200, required=False)
    transactionID = IntegerField(label='Comms Transaction ID', max_value=9223372036854775807, min_value=-9223372036854775808, required=False)
    source = IntegerField(label='Originating source for event', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, required=False)
    target = IntegerField(label='Target destination for event', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, required=False)
    priority = IntegerField(label='Comms priority', max_value=2147483647, min_value=-2147483648, required=False)
    complete_req = IntegerField(read_only=False)
    complete = IntegerField(read_only=False)
    URI = ParameterisedHyperlinkedIdentityField(lookup_fields=(('control_sys', 'sysID'), ('transactionID', 'tID')), read_only=True, view_name='comms-detail')
```

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. Indeed, a queryset does not have a pk; only the *members* of queryset do.

Comment: Hi @DanielRoseman, yes that makes sense. What I dont understand is why it is getting a queryset in this case. I have passed a queryset to the serlialiser with the many=True as documented. Thus I thought it should be expecting a queryset rather than a single model instance and should be validating it based on this?

Comment: Still haven't got this working. Now looking at custom validation on the serialiser or use of Django REST Framework Bulk https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk